# Making the MainView fill screen on device

Tags: application-development

I have been creating an app in the Ubuntu SDK. I want to make sure that the app fills the screen on the device (phone, tablet, etc.). I do not have a ubuntu phone or tablet to test this functionality.

This is my current height and width:

```
MainView {
    width: units.gu(100) 
    height: units.gu(75)
```

Will the app automatically be set to full screen? If so, does that mean the width of the screen is set to 100 grid units and the height of the screen is set to 75 grid units?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In non-windowed mode, meaning on a tablet or phone, the app will take up the full size of the screen, being anchored to the sides and the bottom of the top bar.

The width and height are only used by `qmlscene` on the desktop, meaning that is the size it will appear when run on the desktop. It should not affect the size of the app when run on a tablet or phone.

You can think of it as clicking Maximize when running on a desktop; even though you've set the size, the app can still be maximized.

Comment: This is correct